# Asynchronous programming using async/await

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I am having a tough time understanding async / await. Lets say I have a class A and class B. Class A returns a ActionResult from wcf service method. Before that it calls a async method from another class using await. Does this mean that await `obj.method(param1)` will be running asynchronously and without waiting for the completion of its execution, wcfservice method will execute ? or does it wait until it gets completed?

I wanted that somemethod() should continue its execution without waiting for the result of the method in classB. How will I be able to achieve this?

```
public async classA
{
    public async IHttpActionResult  somemethod
    {
        classB obj  = new classB();
        await obj.method(param1);
        returnok(somewcfservice.method());
    }

public classB
{
    public async Task method(param)
    {
        obj.somebuiltinmethod(param)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is not valid. `somemethod()` cannot use `await` without itself being `async`. The question is also very broad. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. You should research language features. If you still have questions, be _specific_ and be sure to explain what research you've already done. If you want `somemethod()` to complete normally without waiting, then don't wait (i.e. don't use `await`).

Answer (score -1):

*1. Does this mean that await obj.method(param1) will be running aysnchronously and without waiting for the completion of its execution, wcfservice method will execute ? or does it wait until it gets completed?*

**await obj.method(param1);** will wait until the obj.method finishes execution before resuming the execution flow. Thi means the **obj.method(param1);** finishes and then the web service method will be called.

*2.  I wanted that somemethod() should continue its execution without waiting for the result of the method in classB. How will I be able to achieve this?*

you can do something like this :

```
var task = obj.method(param1);
var result = somewcfservice.method()
Task.WaitAll(task);
returnok(result);
```

Comment: _"await obj.method(param1); will wait until the obj.method finishes"_ -- no, it won't. It will simply fail to compile, because `somemethod()` isn't an `async` method. _"you can do something like this :"_ -- no, that's the opposite of what he seems to be asking for. Your example will block the thread until the task completes. He's specifically asked for the `somemethod()` method to continue execution (and presumably return) _"**without waiting**"_ (his words).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree that the code does not compile, but it I think that he will realise soon. Well just creating a task and not waiting to be run is beyond my imagination!